# html form buttons redirect to same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 buttons in my page. I just want to redirect to `Addform.php` page only when I click on `submit` button. But my code will redirect to that page from both `submit` and `reset` button.

```
<form id= "myForm" action= "Addform.php" method= "post">
                    First name:
                    <input type="text" id="fname"><br/><br/>
                    Last name:
                    <input type="text" id="lname"><br/><br/>
                    Age:
                    <input type="text" id="age"><br/><br/>
                    Major Subject:
                    <select id="select">
                      <option value="">---</option>
                      <option value="op1">Mathematics</option>
                      <option value="op2">Computer</option>
                      <option value="op3">Statistics</option>
                    </select><br/><br/>
                    GPA:
                    <input type="text" id="gpa"><br/><br/>

                <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="validation()" value= "submit">Submit</button>
                <button id="btnReset" onclick= "resetForm()">Reset</button><br/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Submit button send form to Addform.php but close button dont send, it just refreshing page and deleting inputs.

Comment: `<input type="reset"` ... doubt you need the JavaScript

Comment: `<button type="reset">...</button>`, and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must code like this
with type of button they dident submit the form
simple way is set type of  button like this `type = "reset"`

```html
<form id= "myForm" action= "Addform.php" method= "post">
                    First name:
                    <input type="text" id="fname"><br/><br/>
                    Last name:
                    <input type="text" id="lname"><br/><br/>
                    Age:
                    <input type="text" id="age"><br/><br/>
                    Major Subject:
                    <select id="select">
                      <option value="">---</option>
                      <option value="op1">Mathematics</option>
                      <option value="op2">Computer</option>
                      <option value="op3">Statistics</option>
                    </select><br/><br/>
                    GPA:
                    <input type="text" id="gpa"><br/><br/>

                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="validation()" value= "submit">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnReset" onclick= "resetForm()">Reset</button><br/>
<!-- or -->
<!--<button type="reset" >Reset</button>-->

            </form>
```

Comment: You said `type = "reset"` but your answer doesn't include that

Answer (score -1):

`button` by default submits the form. Use `input` instead:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="validation()" value= "Submit">
<input type="button" id="btnReset" onclick= "resetForm()" value="Reset">
```

Alternatively I think you can still use button but you must prevent the default behaviour.

Using plain javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button").forEach((item, index)=>{
    item.addEventListener('onclick', function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
})
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: <button> and using <input> as a button doing samething, no difference.

Comment: He's already using javascript: onclick="validation()" / onclick="resetForm()"

Comment: @Dilek not true. `button` automatically submits the DOM form when clicked. `input` with `type="button"` doesn't do anything. And that's the behaviour expected by OP.

Comment: I can still see your edited answer, the one I commented on, nvm your answer is still wrong, he is using javascript as you said, you are giving jquery example, which makes no sence :)